# Brownian motion and physical meaning

Tags: brownian-motion

I have read [Stochastic Differential Equations by Bernt Oksendal](https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tFP1zc0SspNi68yMjBg9DIuLslPzkgsLslMVkjJTEtLLUrNK8lMzFFILSxNLMnMzytWSKpUSEotyitRyM8uTs1LScwBABDJGD8&q=stochastic+differential+equations+by+bernt+oksendal&rlz=1C1NDCM_enZA861ZA861&oq=Stochastic+Differential+Equations+by+Bernt+Oksendal&aqs=chrome.1.0j46j0l2.3195j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)
It constructs Brownian motion by Kolmogorov extension theorem by consider $p(t,x,y)=(2\pi t)^{-n/2} e^{- \frac{|x-y|^{2}}{2t}}$
But I can't understand what is the relation to the Brownian motion in physics.

Comment: I found E. Nelson: "Dynamical Theories of Brownian Motion", https://web.math.princeton.edu/~nelson/books/bmotion.pdf nice to read. It discusses the history and the connection of Wiener processes with more realistic stochastic particle dynamics.

Comment: It kindoff gives a proof for the existence of atoms, is this the kind of thing you are looking for ?